# Proper way for testing application update on iOS?

Tags: iphone, testing

Some posts say testing update on simulator is just as good as installing new ipa over old ipa through itunes for testing update.

ie, are the steps below sufficient for application update testing?

1. Install version 1 through iPhone simulator.
2. Do some data modification/testing on version1.
3. Install version 2 through iPhone simulator.
4. Make sure everything works as expected.

or should I do instead?

1. Install version 1 ipa through itunes.
2. Same as above
3. Install version 2 ipa through itunes.
4. Same as above

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simulator is **not** a substitute for proper testing on a device. There are differences in behavior between the simulator and the device that has bitten all too many a dev, not to mention that the simulator cannot simulate certain hardware directly.

If you are testing on iOS 4, you can use OTA installs to ease some of the hassles of testing through iTunes.

[Link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html)

Answer (score 0):

As for me - the second variant. Of course device because simulator does not support some features (f.e. push notifications).

Steps are next:
1) Install version 1
2) Do some actions (prefere open levels, buy something (levels, things, ...), pass some turns if it is game or guess something)
3) Install a new version on the old (I prefer install from the TestFlight App.)
4) Test a new version: all new features should work properly, all passed levels should be passed, all turns, money, score, purchases, open levels, ... should be opened, bought, ... (as they were in the old version

Do no forget to test the interaction of the old and new version. Especially it refers to pushes (sometimes pushes from the old version do not come to the device with a new) and sending games, presents, messages...